# how field xpages can accept other value

Tags: list, field, xpages

How programming field in xpages that able to accept other value not in the list?

Example field choice values list:
1. Fried Rice
2. Hot Dog
3. Beef Steak
4. Other...

How to simulate choice "Other" value?
In Notes Client programming, we can use field, set accept value not in the list. How we can do it in xpages?

I have tried combobox, set values list, but it doesn't can accept value not in the list

Answer (score 4):

Use `xe:djComboBox` [Dojo Combo Box](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino%20Designer%20XPages%20Extension%20Library#action=openDocument&res_title=djComboBox_Dojo_Combo_Box_ddxl853&content=pdcontent) from Extension Library. User can select values *and* input new values.

Example:

```xml
<xe:djComboBox id="djComboBox1" value="#{sessionScope.test}">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Maine"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="New Hampshire"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Vermont"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Massachusetts"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Rhode Island"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Connecticut"></xp:selectItem>
</xe:djComboBox>
```

[image]

Comment: An Edit Box with typeahead was the approach for the Discussion Template, but the Dojo Combo Box is much more elegant for this kind of approach, where you want users to see all the options available.

Comment: Dear Knut, i tried put your code in my xpages, but there error say "xe is not bound". What should i do?

Comment: You need to add `xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"` as a parameter to `xp:view`. Just drag an(y) Extension Lib control to your XPages and delete it - this way the parameter gets added automatically.

Comment: How to bind the field on document1 field "menu"?

Comment: You can bind your field with `value="#{document1.menu}"`

Comment: If you have a multivalue field in your document1 which contains the choice values list then you would use `<xp:selectItems value="#{document1.menuList}" />`